# IIS Express 10 Configuration Resets

Tags: windows, iis-express

I am having an annoying problem with **IIS Express v10** using **Windows 10**, and **Visual Studio Enterprise 2015**.

Basically our web applications we must have bound to allow remote connections through host names. This is easy to achieve we simply set the configuration as an example below.

```
<site name="WebApplication" id="26">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\WebApps\WebApplication" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44371:*" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

This configuration always worked in previous IIS Express instances. The issue I am facing is everytime I restart the workstation IIS will create another instance of the web application bindings however will be defaulted again to only allow `localhost` as listed below. (Note it also adds (1+) to the name).

```
<site name="WebApplication(1)" id="28">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\WebApps\WebApplication" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44371:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

This has only started happening since using Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express 10. Now daily I just go and reset each of the web applications (we have about 5-6) bindings back to allow remote connections.

Now somewhere I seen this issue arise when having the option `Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)` selected. However on all my applications have ensured these are all `unchecked`.

Additionally I run Visual Studio as `Administrator` using the `Run As Administrator` option selected on the short cut properties. I also have `UAC` disabled (as I hate those prompts).

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, Nico.

Comment: I believe it is a Visual Studio issue where it enforces localhost host name. Not sure if there is a setting to change but you should report to Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to find a resolution (which appears to be more of a workaround) but anyway to resolve this I was able to just to add another binding to initial site configuration to allow remote connections. Basically adding

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44371:*" />`

To my existing binding such as below

```
<site name="WebApplication(1)" id="28">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\WebApps\WebApplication" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44371:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44371:*" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Was able to resolve this. Now again it feels like a work around as actually the initial binding is duplicated.